# Where can I ask about "Story Impressions" on Facebook apps?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a question about Facebook:

> I have an app that says: 157,116 Story Impressions. I am wondering if this is how many times it was displayed on a Facebook page. Is this correct?

Where can I ask it?

Comment: there is [webapps.se]. Check if you can find your answer there.

Comment: Something to do with stackoverflow or stackexchange?

Answer (score 2):

Web Applications seems the best fit for this. Their [about](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/about) page shows that you can ask questions for Facebook:

> Ask about…
>
> - Using a website which **behaves like an application**

…and their "What topics can I ask about here?" in the help center says…

> If your question generally covers …
>
> - Using Gmail, Facebook, Twitter, Google, or any other website which **behaves like an application**

---

Indeed, it appears that you've done just this:

- [What are Story Impressions on Facebook apps?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/52367/what-are-story-impressions-on-facebook-apps)